# Android integer conversion from EditText failed

Tags: java, android, integer, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to set a value in a Handler from a Dialog edittext but i get an error. The code is this:

```
private Button btnstart;
private Button btnstop;
TimePicker myTimePicker;
final static int RQS_1 = 1;
TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog;
Context context;
private int n = 0;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    btnstart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnstart);
    btnstart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LayoutInflater l = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
            View dview = l.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
            AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            ad.setView(dview);
            final EditText edit = (EditText) dview.findViewById(R.id.edit);
            String e = edit.getText().toString();

            n = Integer.parseInt(e);

            ad.setCancelable(false)
            .setTitle("Imposta i Secondi")
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                        @Override
                        public void run(){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }, n);

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){

                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alertD = ad.create();

            alertD.show();
        }
    });
```

the `n` value, usually could be 3000,4000,5000 or any other value in ms as integer value. So i converted the edit value of edittext in integer but i get an error in the logcat:
`Invalid int ""` at line `n = Integer.parseInt(e);` what's wrong here?

Comment: Please, indent your code.

Comment: Could you please indent your code? It's very hard to read it, like this...

Comment: Now, define "get an error". What error? What message? Where?

Comment: this is the only error i get in the logcat: `Invalid int ""`

Comment: the app crashes when i click over the button `btnstart`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move these two lines of code from where they are now to inside the onClick handler of the DialogInterface.OnClickListener.

```
String e = edit.getText().toString();
n = Integer.parseInt(e);
```

#### revised code

```
private Button btnstart;
private Button btnstop;
TimePicker myTimePicker;
final static int RQS_1 = 1;
TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog;
Context context;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    btnstart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnstart);
    btnstart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LayoutInflater l = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
            View dview = l.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
            AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            ad.setView(dview);
            final EditText edit = (EditText) dview.findViewById(R.id.edit);

            ad.setCancelable(false)
            .setTitle("Imposta i Secondi")
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){

                    String e = edit.getText().toString();
                    int n = Integer.parseInt(e);

                Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                        @Override
                        public void run(){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }, n);

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){

                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alertD = ad.create();

            alertD.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Works perfectly.. So the problem was that i wrote the code outside the  onClick?

Comment: You were trying to read the value of the EditText as soon as it was created.  At that point it was empty so that is why you were getting the error. Placing the logic inside the onClick event gives the user an opportunity to enter a value before you attempt to read it.  You should however validate that entry.  If the user enters anything other than an inter value, the app will throw an exception.  You can use a try catch block but I would use a digitsonly regex.

Answer (score 0):

At what point does your `EditText` get populated?  This is in a create event so it appears that you are trying to extract an integer from an empty string?

Comment: The application crashes when i click the `btnstart` button..i can't display the dialog.. If instead `@Override
                        public void run(){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }, n);` i write `@Override
                        public void run(){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }, 3000);` it works

Answer (score 0):

```
int value;
try{
    value = Integer.parseInt(stringValue);
}(Execption e){
    value = 0; // If edittext contains letters, space, etc
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Try to explain what you are doing when posting your code as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

First , you should use try catch for formatting numbers.

```
String e = edit.getText().toString().trim();
   if(e!=null && !e.isEmpty())
    {
           int n ;
            try {
         n = Integer.valueOf(e);
       } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         n = 0;
       }
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: mmh, no crashes...but the toast `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` appears when i press ok button..seems it not takes the value from edittext. If i write 6000 i expect that after 6 seconds appears the toast.

Comment: Its look like you have a problem with the value you take from edittext. can you please print to log the value before you start the handler?